# Wpf Scrollviewer and ScrollChanged event

Tags: c#

My task is to create scrollviewer with images. At first I dont want to load them all. I want to load 50 images and when the scroll slider is about half then load another 50 pictures and so on.

My start point:

```
        if (MyContent.VerticalOffset == MyContent.ScrollableHeight / 2 && MyContent.VerticalOffset != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Half");
        }
```

First problem is When i slide too fast, event doesn't fire.
Maybe have already some solution for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only checking if `VerticalOffset` is equal to `ScrollableHeight`. User can avoid this one single spot by moving the scroll bar very fast. Events are not fired that frequent, so you should check if `VerticalOffset` is past half. You can achieve this by changing operator from `==` to `>=`:

```
if (MyContent.VerticalOffset >= MyContent.ScrollableHeight / 2 && MyContent.VerticalOffset != 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Past Half");
}
```